# Run application on system without Nvidia

Tags: linux, nvidia, dependency-management

I have built an executable with Qt framework and I want to ship the file to customer. Both me and the customer have Ubuntu 20.04 and Qt 5.13.1. To be sure that my program runs on customer PC I used `ldd` command and it gave me the following:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff614aa000)
libqwt-qt5.so.6 => /lib/libqwt-qt5.so.6 (0x00007fcc1e8e6000)
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007fcc1e092000)
libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Multimedia.so.5 (0x00007fcc1dd82000)
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fcc1d536000)
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007fcc1d2ee000)
libQt5Qml.so.5 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5 (0x00007fcc1cc4e000)
libQt5Network.so.5 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007fcc1c89c000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fcc1c0ed000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fcc1bf0c000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fcc1bdbd000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fcc1bda2000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcc1bbb0000)
libQt5Svg.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Svg.so.5 (0x00007fcc1bb52000)
libQt5OpenGL.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 (0x00007fcc1baf6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcc1bad3000)
libGL.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fcc1b787000)
libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 (0x00007fcc1b781000)
libpulse.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007fcc1b72c000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcc1b601000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fcc1b5e5000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fcc1b5da000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcc1b5d4000)
libicui18n.so.56 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007fcc1b13b000)
libicuuc.so.56 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007fcc1ad81000)
libicudata.so.56 => /home/rahimi/Programs/Qt5.13.1/5.13.1/gcc_64/lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007fcc1939e000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fcc19399000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcc1f099000)
libnvidia-tls.so.340.108 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.340.108 (0x00007fcc19196000)
libnvidia-glcore.so.340.108 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.108 (0x00007fcc16582000)
libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fcc16443000)
libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fcc1642e000)
libpulsecommon-13.99.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-13.99.so (0x00007fcc163ae000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fcc1635d000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fcc162ea000)
libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fcc162be000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fcc16211000)
libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007fcc16205000)
libsndfile.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007fcc16188000)
libasyncns.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007fcc15f82000)
libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fcc15f7a000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fcc15f72000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fcc15f49000)
liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fcc15f28000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fcc15e0a000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fcc15ded000)
libFLAC.so.8 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007fcc15daf000)
libogg.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007fcc15da0000)
libvorbis.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007fcc15d72000)
libvorbisenc.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007fcc15cc7000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fcc15cab000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fcc15c91000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fcc15c6e000)
```

there are `libnvidia-tls.so.340.108` and `libnvidia-glcore.so.340.108` among dependencies. But when I use `readelf -d executable | grep NEEDED` command the output is:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libqwt-qt5.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Widgets.so.5]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Multimedia.so.5]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Gui.so.5]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Sql.so.5]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Qml.so.5]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Network.so.5]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libQt5Core.so.5]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

my question is if my customer doesn't have the NVIDIA graphic card and libs, is he/she able to execute my app?
I have done the search but results are mostly related to CUDA lib which is unrelated to my situation here.
Thanks.

Comment: `ldd` lists recursive dependencies, not immediate dependencies. If *you* have nvidia, then *your* libGL (or some other system library)  references nvidia libraries, and they get listed.

Comment: It might. You have to test it. Basically, I believe libQt5Core.so.5 depends on libQt5OpenGL.so.5 which means Qt is using OpenGL as underlying API. In general, competing openGL implementation might work, or not, depending on implementation level (OpenGL 1, 2, 3, 4, ...), implementation quality etc